# Dynamic checkbox only eveluates to true

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, checkbox, dynamic-binding

I have a dynamic checkbox generated trough an iterator.I want to be able to get the true and false values from the current state of the checkbox.

When ik check or uncheck my checkbox is always results in a true value as I would like to get the current state of the checkbock after selection.

Component

```
 <aura:attribute name="checkboxValue" type="Boolean" default="true" />

     <aura:handler name="change"
                  value="{!v.checkboxes}"
                  action="{!c.populateCheckboxes}"
                  description=""/>

   <aura:attribute name="records" type="object[]" description="" access="private" /> 
    <div style="width:100%" class="slds-align_absolute-left">
     {!v.objectName}
         <aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="item" indexVar="indx"> 
                 <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" 
                                   value="{!item.checkboxValue}" 
                                   text="{!item.fieldName}" 
                                   name="{!indx}" 
                                   label="{!item.fieldName}" 
                                   change="{!c.Techniek}"/>{#item.val}      
            </aura:iteration>
```

Javascript

```
 if(component.get('v.checkboxValue') == true){
          console.log('test1');
        }

        if(component.get('v.checkboxValue') == false){
       console.log('test2');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the "`ui:inputCheckbox`" I would recommend you fetch the value using `event.getSource()`. Although the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputCheckbox.htm) seems to indicate you can use `component.get('v.value')`, however, the documented method seems to return 'undefined', therefore, you might want to check [Event Handling in Base Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm)

So, in your function you will want to do:

```
var checkboxVale = event.getSource().get('v.value');
 if(checkboxVale == true){
//Do something
    }
else{
//Do something else
    }
```